# harmonic conjugate for the $u(x,y)=x^3 +2xy-4xy^2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

If $$u(x,y)=x^3 +2xy-4xy^2$$ find the harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$ and explain why the function is entire!

So I tried to solve it and that's what I got

$$ux=3x^2+2y-4y^2$$

$$uy=2x-8xy$$

after applying Cauchy-Riemann Equations

$$vy=ux=3x^2+2y-4y^2$$

and after integration

$$v(x,y)=3x^2y+y^2-(4/3) y^3+\beta(X)$$

and after trying to solve for $\beta$ 
I found it equal to

$$\beta=x^2y-x^2$$

and after applying it to the

$$v(x,y)= 4x^2+y^2=(4/3)y^3-x^2$$

which in obviously is not applying C-R equations if we want to prove the solution is correct and ux is not equal to vy !!!

So does this function is not analytic or entire at all or I am doing something wrong in somewhere!

regards .

Comment: There are several mistakes in your integration step. You should have had $3x^2 y + y^2 - \frac 4 3 y^3 + \beta(x)$, so your first and third terms are incorrect.

Comment: ok,,,i wrote it wrongly , so let me fix it please ,thanks

Comment: No answer yet guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ is not harmonic because $u_{xx}+u_{yy}\neq0$ so it won't have a harmonic conjugate.

Comment: that's what i found sir , but will the professor accept it ? that is the problem . regards

Comment: Why do you think we know what your professor will accept?  Also, why should we care?

Answer (score 0):

The function is not harmonic, so it cannot have a conjugate.

On the other hand, if we fix the example as
$$
u(x,y)=x^3+2xy-\color{red}{3}xy^2,
$$
then
\begin{alignat}{2}
u_x&=3x^2+2y-3y^2 &\qquad\qquad u_{xx}&=6x \\[4px]
u_y&=2x-6xy       &             u_{yy}&=-6x
\end{alignat}
and this $u$ is harmonic.

The harmonic conjugate $v$ must satisfy
$$
v_x=-u_y \qquad\qquad v_y=u_x
$$
Thus
$$
v_x=-2x+6xy \qquad\qquad v_y=3x^2+2y-3y^2
$$
Hence
$$
v=-x^2+3x^2y+f(y)
$$
and
$$
v_y=3x^2+\beta'(y)
$$
that gives $\beta'(y)=2y-3y^2$, so $\beta(y)=y^2-y^3$ (plus an arbitrary constant).

Hence 
$$
v(x,y)=-x^2+3x^2y+y^2-y^3.
$$

You can show that
$$
f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=z^3-iz^2
$$

Comment: yes i know if the example is $x^3+2xy-3xy^2$ is harmonic because the professor give us both of them and i solved this one but the one that i am asking for is my problem ! thanks

Comment: @SmbYouz Since $u_1=x^3+2xy-3xy^2$ is harmonic, if also $u_2=x^3+2xy-4xy^2$ is harmonic, then $u_3=xy^2$ would also be, which clearly isn't, because its Laplacian is $2x$. There's *no* way you can find a harmonic conjugate to a non harmonic function.

Comment: You are absolutely Right . Special Thanks For you .